# Confusion related to norm of dft

Tags: dft

I have this confusion. I was reading this [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/119050/PASTE-sigmod10.pdf). It says

lets say I have a n dimensional vector X and I take its DFT i.e DFT(X). Then the n Fourier coefficients have the same L2 norm as X. How is it true? I tried on a vector

X = ones(100,1). Applied DFT to X i.e, DFT(X). But norms are not equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the scaling factors used in your DFT/IDFT implementation. There is an arbitrary scaling factor that differs by implementation. Specifically, if you take an input vector $x$ and round-trip it via a DFT followed by an IDFT:

$$
y = IDFT(DFT(x))
$$

Then you may see a couple different results in common implementations:

- $y = x$
- $y = Nx$, where $N$ is the transform length

Other cases that I wouldn't be too surprised to see:

- $y = \sqrt{N}x$
- $y = \frac{1}{N}x$
- $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}x$

Which one of these that you see depends on which scaling factors are used in the forward and reverse transforms. If you want the norm of the DFT of $x$ and the norm of $x$ to be the same, then you want the [unitary DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_unitary_DFT) definition:

$$
X[k] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{\frac{-j2\pi k n}{N}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I think the authors refer to [Parseval's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem), the DFT version of which is given by

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}|x(n)|^2=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|X(k)|^2$$

where $X(k)$ is the DFT of $x(n)$. So apart from the scaling factor $1/N$ both $x(n)$ and $X(k)$ have the same norm. You should be able to reproduce this result in Matlab or Octave.